# travis-ci: how to move or rename a file

Tags: travis-ci

Before deployment, (or after, but this is harder as we are deploying to `s3`), we need to rename `staging.robots.txt` to `robots.txt` (overwriting the default `robots.txt`) for the staging deployment only, so that we can block crawling on our staging server (but allow it on production).

Any idea if this is possible?

On the Travis documentation site, there is no info on the `before_deploy` stage, and we cant see any feature to rename files. With Jenkins, I would simply put `cp xxx yyy` or similar in the build script, as I know my Jenkins is running on Ubuntu, but we don't know the equivalent Travis command for the `.travis.yml` file.

**== UPDATE ==**

Having done more research, it might be possible to do this through a script e.g. commit `move.sh` into your repo, then call it. As you can choose what OS the build is done one (e.g. Linux), you can write the script for that platform. However, it's not clear at what point you can call this script in the `.yml` file.

Comment: Where do you want to do that? Rename the file? Where is it created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply write a script to invoke in your `.travis.yml` file for deployment. See the [documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/script/).

Here's the example copied from these docs:

```
deploy:
  provider: script
  script:   scripts/deploy.sh
  on:
    tags:   true
    branch: master
```

The above config for `deploy` would invoke on tagging the `master` branch and the the script (`scripts/deploy.sh`) would be invoked.

Other than that, you can simply write this command under `before_install` section like this:

```
before_install:
- mv abc.txt xyz.txt
```

You've used `cp` command but you are talking about renaming, not copying. So, I've used `mv` command to rename the file.

If you want to do something at the end, you can add an `after_success` section as well.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Interesting - I didnt know you can make OS calls directly, could not find this in the online docs.  This makes things MUCH easier!

Comment: @JohnLittle: What do you mean by `OS calls`? Are you referring to shell commands?

Comment: The next question, for bonus points, is is there any way to make the mv conditional?  E.g. - if "($TRAVIS_TAG)" then mv x.txt y.txt

Comment: @JohnLittle: You can add environment variables in Travis CI WebUI e.g. `$TRAVIS_TAG` that may be used to create such conditions. See the documentation (https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Defining-Variables-in-Repository-Settings).